# Using grep in UNIX with wildcards

Tags: unix, grep, special-characters

I am trying to find a 5 letter words in a file that begins with an upper or lowercase d, followed by a vowel, and ending with a lowercase s. The word can also include special characters as long as it meets the 5 letter limit. This is the command I have come up with and works except for one entry that does not meet the requirements. It returns "Doris's", which is a 6 character word. Can someone give me some direction as to what I'm doing wrong? I have searched online and cannot find anything that specifically relates to this.

`grep -w '[dD][aeiouy]..[s]' /usr/share/dict/words`

Comment: Word "Doris" satisfies the pattern so it returns that line. You can fix your regex by adding a '$' at the end.

Comment: also, you should add ^ at the start of your regex. It should look something like this:  grep -w '^[dD][aeiouy]..[s]$' /usr/share/dict/words

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What "grep" is doing that you don't realize is that it's printing all the lines that contain "Doris" as a whole word, whether it's preceded or followed by anything or not.

So it sees "Doris's", and since it contains the whole word "Doris", it prints it out.

It would also print out the line "I love Doris, who is eating a cookie" since it also contains "Doris" as a whole word.

To get the behavior you want, add "^" and "$" to your regexp, like this:

```
grep -w '^[dD][aeiouy]..[s]$' /usr/share/dict/words
```

That'll make sure that "Doris" only matches if it's the only text in the line.

But if you're looking through a "words" file (with one word per line), you really don't need grep's "-w" switch, as it already has (pretty much) one word per line.

So try this:

```
grep '^[dD][aeiouy]..[s]$' /usr/share/dict/words
```

Note:  If '^' and '$' won't work for you, try replacing "grep" with "egrep", like this:

```
egrep '^[dD][aeiouy]..[s]$' /usr/share/dict/words
```

Comment: I have tried this and when I do, it does not return anything at all.

Comment: Try this with egrep, then:

egrep '^[dD][aeiouy]..[s]$' /usr/share/dict/words